# How can i change multiple columns using the same condition in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to recode some columns in my data, there are 29 columns with the same coded expressions

The cells are coded with numbers, something like that:

1 - Normal
2 - Altered
3 - NA

I want to create a for loop to change all columns at the same time. I need to transform the number code (1;2;3) into names(Normal;Alteres;NA)

thats what im trying to do.... i dont get any error message but this arent working....

```
for (i in names(df[,123:151])){
  mutate(i = case_when(
    i == 1 ~ 'Normal',
    i == 2 ~ 'Altered',
    i == 3 ~ 'NA'))
  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do this would be to use dplyr from tidyverse.

```
library(tidyverse)

#make test dataframe
col1 <- c("1", "2", "3")
col2 <- c(3, 2, 2)
df <- data.frame(col1, col2)

df_recoded<-df %>%
   mutate(across(.cols = everything(), ~case_when(
    . == 1 ~ 'Normal',
    . == 2 ~ 'Altered',
    . == 3 ~ NA_character_)))
```

Comment: The original question specified columns 123:151, so I'd replace `mutate(across(.cols = everything(),` with `mutate(across(123:151,` for the real data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df %>% mutate(across(.cols = names(df)[121:151],
.fns = ~recode(.,`1` = "Normal", `2` = "Altered", `3` = "NA",.default=NA_character_)))
```